# MIN/MAX IF returns #VALUE

Tags: excel

```
Type  | Number
hello | 1
world | 2
zzz   | 3
zzz   | 4
hello | 5

=MIN(IF(A:A="hello", B:B)) //returns #VALUE!
```

I want to find the minimum `Number` if the `Type` is "hello". However, the formula shown returns an error.

What is the correct formula?

Comment: It should be an array formula - enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Or try minifs()

Answer (score 0):

Bigben is right here, it is na array formula...

https://www.lifewire.com/combine-the-min-and-if-functions-3123299